# Cannot retrieve json with ajax request from java/spring rest entry point

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have a REST entry point embedded in a class with annotation `@RestController`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public String getReitByDateRangeAdDoGeographic(){
                return "{\"msg\":\"success\"}";
            }
```

and I try to request it using ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: URL,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("SUCCESS");
    },
    error: function (a,b, result) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

when I look at the http response in the browser, it is correct:

```
{
    "msg": "success"
}
```

but the error callback is always called with the message (the HTTP code is 200):

```
14:19:00,855 Error: jQuery1113010493236335514322_1517318340103 was not called
Trace de la pile :
.error@http://localhost:63342/Sankey/external-lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2:1809
b.converters["script json"]@http://localhost:63342/Sankey/external-lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:27779
Pb@http://localhost:63342/Sankey/external-lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:18379
x@http://localhost:63342/Sankey/external-lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:21793
.send/b.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:63342/Sankey/external-lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:27067
 1 generateSankey.js:22:3
```

Do you have an idea why? Is it a parsing problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue thanks to this nice post : http://www.baeldung.com/spring-jackson-jsonp.

It is due to the "same-origin policy". To solve this, I created the class

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JsonpAdvice extends AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice {

    public JsonpAdvice() {
        super("callback");
    }

}
```

Then, the ajax request looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: requestParam,
    jsonpCallback: 'stringCallback',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("SUCCESS");
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (a,b, result) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(result);
    }
});

function stringCallback(json){
    console.log(json);
}
```